# Remaining space after fixed side navigation bar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im trying to make a website that has a side navigation bar that is fixed and defined in pixels as i need it to remain the same size regardless of window size. However the rest of the page needs to be responsive.
The problem i have is that as the navigation bar is defined in pixels and the rest of the page is in percentage i have a horizontal scroll bar that i do not want. I am looking for a way to only use the horizontal space left over in the window, ie minus the pixels used by the navigation?
Thanks

Comment: What percentages define the rest of the page? How many pixels wide is the navigation bar? What browser are you using to view the page? How wide is the browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a job for css calc:

```
width:90%;
width:calc(100% - 90px);
```

note that we first write the width without the calc as a fallback for old browsers.

http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

Comment: Thank you, great concise answer !

Answer (score 0):

I believe that setting

```
overflow-x:hidden
```

in your CSS, you will prevent horizontal scrollbars from appearing.

Comment: It does but margins attached to the left hand side of the screen don't appear as they should as they use the hidden width as their marker point. Thanks for the suggestion though!